# How do I translate default submit_tag button text in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

How do you translate default `submit_tag` button text? I can translate `f.submit` as such, but this does not work for forms not handling objects, like password resets:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      user:
        create: "Sign up"
      password_resets:  # doesn't work as password_resets uses form_tag instead of form_for
        create: "Reset Password"
```

Do I have to create my own keys for those?

Comment: If you are using form_tag, You can change in the view file. right..? .Only for "reset password"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: you can also customize submit tag values on a per-model, `password_resets` is model or action?

Comment: `password_resets` is just a controller, not a model. That's why it does not work like the `user.create` does, in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the default translate method? When providing a name value for the submit tag you can use translate to have it translated:

```
<%= submit_tag t("helpers.submit.password_resets.create") %>
```